# expl3 problem, File ended while scanning use of \__file_parse_version:w

Tags: biblatex, pdftex, babel, expl3

today I ran into a problem while compiling a `.tex` document. (I'm compiling with the Sublime Text 3 Build command) The minimal working example looks like this.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\title{Test}
\author{}
\date{}

\tracingcommands=1
\begin{document}
\tracingcommands=0

\maketitle
test

\end{document}
```

The errors listed in the console are

```
TeX STOPPED: File ended while scanning use of \__file_parse_version:2021-01-09\s__file_stop \__int_eval_end: \exp_after:wN \use_ii:nn \fi: 
TeX reports the error was in file:3 \begin{document}
/Users/ondra/Downloads/test.tex:13: Missing number, treated as zero. [\begin{document}]
```

and the warnings

```
/Users/ondra/Downloads/test.tex: LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 15, version `2020/04/06' of package expl3, but only version `2021-01-09 L3 programming layer (loader) ' is available.

/Users/ondra/Downloads/test.log:1: Double-click here to open the full log.
```

I can spot some weird behaviour while looking into the `.log` file.

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
{\def}
{\let}
{\xdef}
{\edef}
{\let}
{\def}
{\def}
{\futurelet}
{\let}
{\futurelet}
{\let}
{\let}
{\let}
{\afterassignment}
{\xdef}
{\let}
{\let}
{\begingroup}
{\let}
{\immediate}
Package: expl3 2021-01-09 L3 programming layer (loader) 
{\endgroup}
{\protected}
{blank space  }
{\protected}
{blank space  }
{\protected}
{blank space  }
{\protected}
{blank space  }
{\protected}
{blank space  }
{\begingroup}
{\endgroup}
{\begingroup}
{\endgroup}
)
Runaway argument?
2021-01-09\s__file_stop \__int_eval_end: \exp_after:wN \use_ii:nn \fi: \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \__file_parse_version:w.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.13 \begin{document}
                     
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \__kernel_tl_set:Nx 
l.13 \begin{document}
                     
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

{begin-group character {}
{\relax}
{\begingroup}
{\def}
{\let}
{\immediate}

LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 13, version
               `2020/04/06' of package expl3,
               but only version
               `2021-01-09 L3 programming layer (loader) '
               is available.

{\endgroup}
{end-group character }}
{\xdef}
{\edef}
{\global}
{\gdef}
{\gdef}
{\catcode}
{\relax}
{\gdef}
{\gdef}
{\xdef}
{\xdef}
{\edef}
{\xdef}
{\xdef}
{\xdef}
{\edef}
{\global}
{\global}
{\global}
{\relax}
{\begingroup}
{\let}
{\let}
{\relax}
{\begingroup}
{\def}
{\let}
{\immediate}
Package biblatex Info: ... but expl3
(biblatex)             2021-01-09 L3 programming layer (loader) 
(biblatex)             is too old (older than 2020/04/06),
(biblatex)             setting 'casechanger=latex2e'.
```

Especially the last lines, where the version `2021-01-09` is treated as older than `2020/04/06`.

I can get rid of this error by either commenting out the line `\usepackage[czech]{babel}` or `\usepackage{biblatex}`. But if they are imported together, the error described above occurs.

My `pdftex -v` console dump:

```
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020)
kpathsea version 6.3.2
Copyright 2020 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.37; using libpng 1.6.37
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with xpdf version 4.02
```

What should I focus on? Should I try to downgrade my L3 programming layer down to the version `2020/04/06`? Thank you for your advice and time in advance.

Comment: Workaround for now: Load `\usepackage{expl3}` before `\usepackage{biblatex}`. (The current version of `biblatex` loads `expl3` very late. Possibly even after Czech has interfered with some category codes, maybe that of `-`...)

Comment: @moewe The problem is indeed the category code of `-`, which is set to active by `babel-czech` *before* `biblatex` does its check about the version of `expl3`. Why doing the check so late?

Comment: Another workaround is to load `biblatex` before `babel`.

Comment: @moewe I wouldn't defer this tests to begindocument. Users should set the input encoding at the begin, before loading packages, and biblatex should be allowed to rely on it. Use the input encoding active when biblatex is loaded, and only test at begin document if something changed to warn that something is wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Update

This issue was resolved in `biblatex` 3.17. Update your TeX system.

---

### Old answer

This issue was caused by `biblatex` delaying loading `expl3` to the last minute when it can make the best guess about the document encoding (this is required since `biblatex` loads different code for the case changer depending on whether or not the document is UTF-8-encoded, see https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1058).

Unfortunately, `expl3` is loaded so late that the Czech language module has already changed the category codes of the hyphen `-`, which causes trouble here.

Since loading the case changing code so late caused trouble in other contexts as well (https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1090), `biblatex` will now try to guess the file encoding when it is loaded and will warn when that guess differs from the guess made later in an `\AtBeginDocument` hook (see https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/15a62fb5bb227db5ef613aaa13778d92bd190f29). This means that `inputenc` and friends should be loaded before `biblatex` (this was always a good idea, but is now necessary to get things right).

The problem will be resolved in the next `biblatex` version (v3.17). In the meantime a workaround would be to load `expl3` explicitly before `biblatex`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! The workaround with loading ```expl3``` before ```biblatex``` worked for me.