# Biblatex causes Runaway argument error

Tags: biblatex, overleaf

I'm making a template for my projects on Overleaf. But I have encountered a problem when using the biblatex package.
I have my `main.tex` file, where all the main document is and a `seminarka.sty` file with all commands and modifications. But when I import biblatex I get a error when building in my `main.tex`.

```
Runaway argument?
2021-07-12\s__file_stop \__int_eval_end: \__prg_T_true:w \fi: \use_none:n \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \__file_parse_version:w.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.6 \begin{document}
                    
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \__kernel_tl_set:Nx 
l.6 \begin{document}
                    
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)


LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 6, version
               `2020/04/06' of package expl3,
               but only version
               `2021-07-12 L3 programming layer (loader) '
               is available.
```

```tex
% main.tex
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{seminarka}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}

\custtitlepage{Název}{Podnázev}{Autor}{Předmět}{Škola}{Datum}

\toc
...
```

This issue is resolved when I remove the `\usepackage{biblatex}` command from `seminarka.sty`, but I need biblatex to make references and citations.

Overleaf project: https://www.overleaf.com/read/wvyjpjqygvwp

Comment: Have you contacted Overleaf's help desk? I hear their LaTeX support staff is top-notch.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I contacted the help desk now. If they come up with a solution I'll make sure I post it here as well.

Comment: Based on the name of the package you load, I'm guessing you might be loading `babel` for Czech or Slovak language support. In that case, please have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/581409/35864.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@moewe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/35864/moewe) said, the problem was with the babel package. The solution to it was either import explicitly `expl3` (as stated [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/581469/260443)) before `biblatex` or move the import of babel after `biblatex`.

#### New package import order

```tex
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{expl3} % optional, not really needed but fixes the problem as well
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[sfdefault,light]{roboto}
\usepackage[hidelinks,pdftex]{hyperref}
```